# Poedit without location comments

Tags: poedit, xgettext

I'd like to have .po-file without path-comments (location). Our team has because of them a lot of trouble during git-merge.

I can get the file without comment using command:

```
$ xgettext --no-location -o input.po output.po
```

BUT! It removes headlines in the file beginning as well. Without those headlines PoEdit does not work correctly.

How can i remove all path-comments but store headlines in *.po file?

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question: use `--no-location`.

`--no-location` does *not* remove the gettext header (which you probably mean by "headlines"). It would make no sense for it to do it and Poedit itself uses it for its own PO(T) file(s).

Your problem is in your command — read `xgettext` manpage, it is for extraction from source code, not manipulating existing PO files (that's what `msgcat` is for).